# Json File to javascript array

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need help loading a "json" file into an array on my html page.

My "Json" file is called "JsonData.json"

```
[
    {
        "ID": 1,
        "Name": "John Smith",
        "IDNumber": "7606015012088"
    },
    {
        "ID": 2,
        "Name": "Molly Malone",
        "IDNumber": "8606125033087"
    },
    {
        "ID": 3,
        "Name": "Rianna Chetty",
        "IDNumber": "6207145122087"
    }
]
```

I need help to load the above "JsonData.json" file into an array which will look like this:

```
 var myList = [
    {
        "ID": 1,
        "Name": "John Smith",
        "IDNumber": "7606015012088"
    },
    {
        "ID": 2,
        "Name": "Molly Malone",
        "IDNumber": "8606125033087"
    },
    {
        "ID": 3,
        "Name": "Rianna Chetty",
        "IDNumber": "6207145122087"
    }

];
```

Comment: To parse JSON: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4935632/how-to-parse-json-in-javascript

Answer (score 1):

Initialize an ajax request to your json file and then it returns the data from the file. For example if **"data"** is what returned from the ajax request, then your array would be

```
var myList = JSON.parse(data);
```

Hope this helps you

Comment: how do I create an ajax request to my json file?

Answer (score 1):

using jQuery:

```
$.getJSON('JsonData.json')
    .done(function(data) {
      alert(data[0].ID);
    });
```

Comment: I tried the code below:

$.getJSON('JsonData.json')
    .done(function (data) {
        var myList = data;
    });

And I get an error
Error: 'myList' is undefined

Comment: @ Linkz Could you please paste the whole code pls